# Blazor Server StateHasChanged Triggers InvalidOperationException

Tags: event-handling, blazor-server-side

I am experiencing an InvalidOperationException on a StateHasChanged call in a Blazor Server app.

The app has a main layout component that contains several child components. Each component registers for an event that's defined in a static class. When the user clicks a button in Child1, it changes some data in a service class and invokes the static class to Throw the event that triggers Child2 to re-render itself via StateHasChanged in its event handler.  That's when the InvalidOperationException is thrown.

I know there is another way to do this by having the components register for an event when any of the data in the service class changes.  My impression is that either my static class event approach or the service event approach are fine, but would like to know if that isn't the case or reasons why the service event approach might be better.

I’ve bypassed the problem using my approach to trigger the master layout to re-render instead of just Child2, but am concerned I’m missing something important because I think my original approach should work.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the exception is a result of threading.  The exception goes away by replacing StateHasChanged() with InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged).  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65230621/statehaschanged-vs-invokeasyncstatehaschanged-in-blazor) and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/16119) for perspective on why.